# popToRoute() not working when I pass in route object

Tags: navigator

I've googled this a bunch and there aren't sufficient examples or explanations that tell me how popToRoute(), the react-native navigator method exactly works. Would be awesome if someone could help me better understand it.

I'm passing in my route object (which is definitely correct) but get the error: "Invariant Violation: Calling popToRoute for a route that doesn't exist!"

Here is the relevant code where I use the popToRoute() navigator method:

```
var InviteRoommates = React.createClass({
  submitRoommates: function() {
    this.props.navigator.popToRoute({
      index: 3,
      id: 'ItemList'
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>INVITE ROOMMATES</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="roommate's email address"/>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.submitRoommates()}
        >
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you find resolution for this one? I am also running in to the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the exact same code as you, have the same problem.  Found a solution that works, although ugly. Access all the route objects with `this.props.navigator.getCurrentRouts()`, then specifying one by it's index in the array.  Of course this only works if you know the route object's position in the stack at all times....

```
this.props.navigator.popToRoute(this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes()[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to popToRoute by name you can simply loop through the route stack and check each route by name, then pop to that route.

```
var routes = this.props.navigator.state.routeStack;
for (var i = routes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(routes[i].name === "MyDestinationRoute"){
    var destinationRoute = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes()[i]
    this.props.navigator.popToRoute(destinationRoute);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
const routes = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
const routeToGo = routes.find( route => route.name == 'the name of the route');
this.props.navigator.popToRoute(routeToGo);
```